# Create and Revoke User Certificate from Web UI in ejbca

Tags: certificate, jboss7.x, ejbca

I am new in ejbca and I have setup ejbca environment on my local machine

now I want to create user certificates and I want to revoke it from Web UI

Is there any way to create and revoke user certificate in ejbca from Web UI and how we can do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steps to create and revoke user certificate from Web UI in ejbca

**To create a cert:**

1. Create an End entity on the Web Admin portal.
2. Go to Public Web of EJBCA and select 'Create Certificate from CSR'
3. Enter the User name and password of End entity. select the CSR you created using openssl or any other tool..
4. Click 'OK', cert for the user will get downloaded..

**To revoke a cert,**

1. Go to Admin Web
2. Select 'Search End Entity' under 'RA Functions'
3. Enter the username and search.
4. Once the user is found, see if the status is 'generated' (means the cert for user is generated)
5. Right side to the record, click view certificate.
6. In the view pop-up, you will find the revovation drop-down, select a reason and click 'revoke.

hope this will help you Cheers...!